# error font when get XML data non-unicode

Tags: xml

I am trying post XML data (with encoding="euc-kr", non utf-8) from client to JSP server page.

XML data have format like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="euc-kr" ?>
<book>
  <id>123456789</id>
  <name>한국어</name>
</book>
```

but on Server page, i can not get exactly font. Getting result return like below:

```
<name>ÇÑ±¹¾î</name>
```

font is error.

I am using JSP (client and server are jsp also).
How i can get exactly front with non-unicode format?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your data is fine. The client is interpreting it as CP1252 instead of EUC-KR.

```
>>> print u'ÇÑ±¹¾î'.encode('cp1252').decode('euc-kr')
한국어
```